# Separated [create] and [store] function's validation doesn't work in Laravel6

Tags: laravel

I'm studying store data using these codes. This code can store data but There is no validation. so I'm trying to add the validation part.
Actually, This is my first time looking at the separated [create] and [store] function
so I wasn't sure how to attach validate function. I tried to adjust the code but it didn't work. Could you teach me the right code, please?

```
public function create() {
    $users  = User::All();
    $users  = User::with('products')->get();

    $categoris  = Categori::All();
    $categoris  = Categori::with('products')->get();

    $creators = Creator::All();
    $creators = User::with('products')->get();
    $creators = DB::table('creators')->where('creators.br_no', Auth::user()->br_id)->get();

    $data = array(
        'title'     => request('title'),
        'kansu'     => request('kansu'),
        'categoris' => $categoris,
        'creators'  => $creators,
        'users'  => $users
    );
    return view('product.create',$data);
}

public function store() {
    Product::create([
        'title'         => request('title'),
        'kansu'         => request('kansu'),
        'creator_id'    => request('creator_id'),
        'user_id'   => request('user_id'),
        'br_id'     => request('br_id'),
        'color_id'  => request('color_id'),
        'categori_id'   => request('categori_id')
    ]);
    return redirect('/product/ownbr');
}
```

> I add this validation top of the code

```
protected function validator(array $data) {
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'creator_id' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'color_id' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'categori_id' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'kansu' => 'required|string|max:255',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that in two way :-
in the top of store method , you can put your validation like this :-

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
        'creator_id' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'color_id' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'categori_id' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'kansu' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);
        Product::create([]);
        return redirect('/product/ownbr');
    }
```

second way , you can create form request by this command ,
php artisan make:request ProductRequest.
you will find this class in app/http/requests
add your validation in rules method

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
            'creator_id' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'color_id' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'categori_id' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'kansu' => 'required|string|max:255',
    ];
}
```

change this also in the same class :

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

then you can use this request in your controller like this :

```
public function store(ProductRequest $request)
{
    Product::create([

    ]);
}
```

i recommend the second way because it separate the validation process from the controller so that the controller be much cleaner